# How to change password and sent mail to customer group programmatically Magento 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Hi Developpers around the world!!!

I have just imported a **new customer group** of 700 Customers from a another CMS in Magento Eshop 1.7.02

So I need to sent to this Customer Group an email 
to inform them that they have a login with their email in my site but
 **automatically**
to send them a new password using Magento build in function of **Changing Current Password**.

How **programmatically** can I sent an email with a new
password to my new Customer Group (only to this group not all customers)?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a blog post](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-reset-passwords-for-all.html) that explains how to reset the passwords for all customers.
The main idea is to generate a new password, assign it to the customer model and then call `sendNewAccountEmail` that sends  the new password by e-mail.
The post explains how to reset the password for all customers but you can manipulate the customer collection to include only your customer group. Something like:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$customers->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', YOUR GROUP ID HERE);
```

Comment: thanks again. I will try to understand it and If I have a issue  I will post it here.